# Generics - return different type object

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5

I have a bunch of methods defined on my interface that look like this:

```
T Map<T>( SomeType someParam );
```

and are implemented like this:

```
public T Map<T>( SomeType someParam )
{
  return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SomeType, T>( someParam );
}
```

How can I simplify my interface so that I just have one method like:

```
T Map<T>(T someParam);
```

and

```
public T Map<T>( T someParam )
{
  return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T, T>( someParam );
}
```

However, when I implement it this way, I get a conversion error about converting from SomeType and another type.  Is this possible to do with generics, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just provide more generic type parameter:

```
public T1 Map<T1,T2>( T2 someParam){
  return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T1, T2>( someParam);
}
```